# SharePoint Online Information Management Policies

Tags: sharepoint-online, information-management, retention, information-policy

I have some questions regarding Information Management Policies in a SharePoint Online environment.

I have taken the required steps to set a retention policy a library.

1. I turned on the Content Organizer feature from the Site Collection Features
2. Got the Web Service URL from the Content Organizer Settings
3. Set a destination called Archive (based on (3)) in the SharePoint Admin's Record Management section
4. Then I created the Information management
   policies on the library and instructed them to "Move and Leave
   link". These libraries have this format: an "Investigation" content
   type (based on folder) and Document content type. For testing
   purposes, I set the policy to expire after 1 day from Created date
   for the document content type and 2 days from Created date for the "Investigation" content type.

I have taken these steps yesterday and I suspect nothing happened yet because there's a default scheduled time when this is supposed to happen which has not been hit yet.

1. Does the information management policy have a scheduled time to run?
   Is it once a week? And when? Where do you get that information from?
   And is it modifiable?
2. Let's say a document "TestDoc" inside a Registration Folder "Reg001"
   expires in the library "Lib" with Information Management Policy set
   with "Archive1" as moving destination, (this would be the first expired
   document) would the library "Archive1" be created, clone "Reg001" as
   a folder just for the sake of moving "TestDoc" inside of it?
3. And then when "Reg001" itself expires, it would already find the
   folder created in the "Archive1" library, and would simply delete it from the "Lib" since it has already been moved?

SharePoint Online Retention policies are still a new, yet exciting area to me. Pressed against time I would rather be sure that I am set on the right track. Am I understanding correctly? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score -2):

> Does the information management policy have a scheduled time to run?
>   Is it once a week? And when? Where do you get that information from?
>   And is it modifiable?

Yes - there is a scheduled time to run this, I had to change mine to make it run once/day.  For testing you can manually run the job on the server too.  I forget what the default is, it might be that the timer job only runs once/week - this is annoying since you can't see whether your policy is working correctly!

I found [this post](http://kimfrehe.com/category/sharepoint/) by Kim Frehe very useful when researching and configuring the information management policy.  Also check out [Jason's answer in this post](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/0989ed09-5495-4e59-b99d-2605ef0c14a2/information-management-policy-retention-not-working?forum=sharepointgeneral) about finding the timer job and testing it.

I can't help on your 2nd and 3rd points as I've used 'In Place Records Management'.  Good luck!

Comment: Am I missing something or do both your links refer to SharePoint On Premise?

Comment: Yes they do.  I deduce from your comment that this would affect the behaviour of the information management policy.  I can't comment, since I've not used SP Online.

Comment: SharePoint Online does not have the same central administration as On Premise, and information on retention in Online is scarce, which is why I asked the question. I am looking into the links just the same, perhaps they'll still prove fruitful somehow

Comment: I checked a blog I often use for info on On Premise, but didn't find much.  His final point in this post says you can not configure a timer job in Online: https://sharepointmaven.com/set-retention-deletion-policies-files-folders-sharepoint/

Comment: the last paragraph sums it up! I had looked at this article but did not get to the last bit, now I did thanks to you :) It sucks that we do not have control over it but at least its there. I guess I'll have to wait and see about point 1 and hope someone can give me some insight re point 2 and 3. thanks!

Comment: You might find something useful amongst these posts regarding SPO timer jobs:  https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bsharepoint-online%5D+timer+job   One or two of the posts I read mention that the default period to wait for the timer job is 1 week.  The first post looks gives possible alternatives - Windows Task Scheduler (I've heard of this), plus some other options.